# Are there restrictions or procedure to follow while reading scriptures?

Tags: scripture, puranas, shiva-purana

If I read holy scriptures like Puranas or Itihasas as hobby on my laptop do I need to follow specific procedures.

Point to be noted here is that I am not narrating it like it it is mentioned in puranas.

Comment: In a nutshell your attitude shows- you called it holy. Moment you have that respect half the purification is done.Now the remaining things are upto you to follow- clean place, atleast wash face and hands with water( with soap is even better). Being clean, quiet, bright I think is enough to read it in modern age. I hope someone gives a mantra before starting - like gananaam ganapatiGm havamahe....